# About the meaning of the word "groundhoggery"

Tags: word-meaning

The title of [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/uk-prime-minister-johnson-declare-220000217.html) says,

> UK Prime Minister Johnson to declare Britain can end 'the **groundhoggery**' of Brexit

So there was no entry in the dictionary nor googling didn't help.

I suspect the word is the combination of the noun "ground" and the verb "hog", defined at 5a or b?

> transitive verb
>
> 1
>   :  to cut (a horse's mane) short :  roach
>
> 2
>   :  to clean the bottom of (a ship) with a hog
>
> 3
>   a :  to cause to arch like the back of a hog
>   b :  to cause (as a ship or timber) to bow up in the middle and sag at the ends usually as a result of improper loading or supporting
>
> 4
>   a British :  to winter over (young sheep)
>   b :  to utilize (an unharvested crop) by turning in hogs to feed — often used with down or off
>
> 5
>   **a :  to take, grasp, or retain selfishly or in excess of one's due or need**
>   
>   
>   **b :  to consume voraciously — usually used with down**
>
> 6
>   :  to play (a curling stone) so as not to pass the hog score
>
> 7
>   :  to tear up or shred (bulk material) into bits with a hog
>
> intransitive verb
>   1
>   :  to become curved upward in the middle like a hog's back — used especially of a ship or its bottom or keel
>   2
>   :  to act like a hog especially in taking more than one's share

meaning (Johnson's going to stop) people voraciously dig into this matter too much, would it?

Comment: Note that although it's "regularly formed", ***groundhoggery*** is an inherently "quirky" coinage. Deliberately so - like Trump, Johnson likes to use weird / memorable phrasing. Which obviously works, since I can still remember him calling table tennis ***wiff-waff***. Here are more examples of [Johnson's colourful phrasing...](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/politics/london-mayor-election/mayor-of-london/10909094/Boris-Johnsons-top-50-quotes.html)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I like his phrase though :). On being prime minister -- My chances of being PM are about as good as the **chances of finding Elvis on Mars**,haha.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a reference to the movie [*Groundhog Day*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day_(film)), where Bill Murray gets stuck repeating the same day over and over again.

Johnson's implication is that the UK is repeating the same actions on Brexit without ever achieving anything.

Comment: it is definitely this answer - never-ending repetition! Being locked into the same routine over and over, essentially forever.